# How to avoid direct DOM manipulation in this case?

Tags: reactjs

New to React (~two weeks), encountered the following problem and unable to google/chatGPT an answer:
I coded an "animated stars background" for my App and a button to toggle animation off/on. Removing irrelevant details, it looks like this:

```
const StarField = ( {numOfStars} ) => {
    const starArray = Array.from({ length: numOfStars }, () =>
        Star({ some position, randomly generated at this point and passed to a child })
    );
    return (
        <> starArray </>
    );
};
```

An individual `Star`, which has a special `name`, which will be attached to all animated objects in the App:

```
const Star = (props) => {
    const style = { ... necessary stuff, animationName: some animation here }
    return (
        <div key={uniqueId()} name='animatedThing' style={style} </div>
    );
};
```

Now, I have a "toggle animation" button elsewhere in `AnimationToggle` component, which should pause and restart all animated elements in the App. There are none other than `Star` objects so far but will be in the future, so I have a Redux state `animate`. And `AnimationToggle` component, apart from the button, toggle animation pause/restart for any object in DOM with a dedicated `name`:

```
const AnimationToggle = () => {
    const animate = useSelector((state) => state.animate.value);
    useEffect(() => {
        const allMovingThings = document.querySelectorAll("[name=animatedThing]");
        allMovingThings.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.animationPlayState = animate ? "running" : "paused";
        });
    }, [animate]);
}
    return (
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(toggleAnimation())}>CLICK !</button>
    );
```

It works nice! My stars pause and resume from current position, opacity, size etc.

But I am bothered that I am manipulating 300 objects directly in DOM, which is a bad practice, though not forbidden.

Now, why not just put `const animate = useSelector((state) => state.animate.value);` line in `Star` object and then assign `animationPlayState` there accordingly? Because I create `Star` children in the loop, and React throws an error, as hooks can't be created in a loop.  Besides, even if I manage to get the `animate` state value inside a it, the `Star` will re-render and restart animation from 0% start.

Ok, but why not get `animate` value in `StarField` parent component and pass it to `Star` children as prop? It works, but not the way i want - again, all the positions are recalculating to new random values and animation timer is reset to 0%. I can imagine creating a wrapper for `StarField`, which will calculate an Array of 300 position values and pass it down, and somehow keep current % position on 300 animations in Redux state ... but it really sounds ugly, and so much extra code.

So a question: is there an elegant "reactonic" way to avoid DOM manipulation in this case?